# python serial read, then overwrite to .txt file

Tags: python, serial-port

semi newbie here, this was working but apparently I broke it, what am I missing? Nothing happens now whereas yesterday the serial data would echo to the screen and save to a file. I tried sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0 but nothing shows as coming in, yet if I connect the usb cable to a windows box the data is there. thx in advance!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# get lines of text from serial port, save them to a file

from __future__ import print_function
import serial, io

    addr  = '/dev/ttyUSB0'  # serial port to read data from
    baud  = 9600            # baud rate for serial port
    fname = '/home/pi/scripts/radar/radarout.txt'   # log file to save data in
    fmode = 'w'             # log file mode = append

    with serial.Serial(addr,baud) as pt, open(fname,fmode) as outf:
    spb = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(pt,pt,1),
        encoding='ascii', errors='ignore', newline='\r',line_buffering=True)
    spb.readline()  # throw away first line; likely to start mid-sentence (incomplete)
    while (1):
        x = spb.readline()  # read one line of text from serial port
        print (x,end='')    # echo line of text on-screen
        outf.write(x)       # write line of text to file
        outf.flush()        # make sure it actually gets written out
```

Comment: How is it "broken"? Is it throwing an error? Is it producing incorrect results? What did you change that broke it?

Comment: is this python 2.x? if so, does the while(1) ever end?